# LWC - promise returns both success and error

Tags: lightning-web-components

On clicking save button in a modal, a JS function is executed:

```
  saveModal() {
    this.openModal = false;
    markImportant({ Id: this.row.Id })
      .then(this.showToast("success"))
      .catch(this.showToast("error"));
  }
```

markImportant is a Apex controller method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void markImportant(String Id){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.id = Id;
    acc.ImportantField__c = true;
    update acc;
}
```

showToast is a method used to display toasts:

```
    showToast(variant) {
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Get Help",
      message:
        "Salesforce documentation is available in the app. Click ? in the upper-right corner.",
      variant: variant
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

I am getting both Error and Success toasts - all executed at once. I presume that the promise returns both success and error? Could you point out my error please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `then()` and [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods take a callback as input parameter, but you're passing just the value (undefined) returned by `showToast()` to both. Indeed you're explicit calling `showToast()` two times, that's why you see both toast messages.

You could use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to handle the data returned by a promise (in `then()`) or the exception (in `catch()`).

You should change your code to:

```js
saveModal() {
    this.openModal = false;
    markImportant({ Id: this.row.Id })
      .then(() => {
          this.showToast("success");
      })
      .catch(() => {
          this.showToast("error");
      });
}
```

This way the `showToast()` method will be called only once the promise is settled.

Comment: Thanks, time to learn some more JS.